# Импортирование sql-файла в базу данных в sqlTools в vscode

Tags: база-данных

[image: вот моя база данных]

Мне нужно в базу данных  foodsys импортировать файл sql
Подскажите как это сделать.

Comment: Скорее всего ваш SQL файл содержит набор sql команд, которые над просто выполнить. Если это не так, то нужно уточнить в вопросе: Какая СУБД, что содержится в SQL файле

Comment: MySql 8.0 установлена у меня, а sql -файл надо импортировать